# dom4j cdata (keep whitespace)

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I'm trying to get cdata text from a node using dom4j java.  My issue here is that all of the line breaks are removed.  Essentially, I need to read the contents of the CDATA as if it were a <pre> tag in HTML.

Do you have any ideas?  I have a very small time to get this done unfortunately so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need XML text to be statically defined as in a CDATA block, it must be flagged this way in the XML as such:

```
<tag><![CDATA[This is
three
lines]]></tag>
```

If your contents is not inside a CDATA section, i.e.:

```
<tag>This is
three
lines</tag>
```

normal XML processing will occur which means that the whitespace is normalised.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, the contents were fine.  I figured out the error, it was a data issue.

**dom4j automatically does NOT remove whitespace in cdata sections.**  I was reading in file contents from a buffered reader and used readLine and did not re-append line breaks, causing the entire xml document to be a 1-liner, causing my cdata section to be one line as well.

Sorry for not responding earlier, I had figured this out a couple of days ago...

Thanks!